# How to run a Spring Boot application for exactly 24 hours?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to create a Spring Boot application and let it run exactly 24 hours. After that the application should exit nicely. I could only think of achieving this goal with an infinate loop and always check current time equals start time + 24 hours. Can anybody please advise?

Please note this is *NOT* to schedule some tasks...

Comment: What environment will the app run in? warfile in application server? standalone jar?

Comment: You can use Chron Job to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically shut down Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944144/programmatically-shut-down-spring-boot-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I compile a java file with a different name than the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841847/can-i-compile-a-java-file-with-a-different-name-than-the-class)

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule a task to execute once: ([Spring scheduling task - run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once)) and close application when task is executed ([Programmatically shut down Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944144/programmatically-shut-down-spring-boot-application))

Answer (score 1):

If you do this on Linux, you can run your Spring Boot Application, and get the process ID.

```
java -jar your-app.jar
```

and use another base script to kill it after 24 hours, like :

```
sleep 24 * 60 * 60
kill -9 <pid_of_your_app>
```