# how to close the application during startup in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a question regarding the startup in `spring boot`, how to close the application during the startup time, for example, I have the following

`application.yml`:

```
ansi:
   true
```

And I have the following `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig {
   @Value('${ansi}')
   String ansi;


   @Bean
   getAnsi() {
        if(ansi.equals("true")) {
             Ansi ansiObj = new Ansi();
             ansiObj.ansi = ansi;
             return ansiObj;
        }
   }
}

class Ansi {
   String ansi;
}
```

When `ansi` in the `application.yml` is `true`, it continue, otherwise, the application should be closed, can we close the application during the bean creation? is it a good practice? Are there any good ways to handle this?

Comment: You may want to check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944144/programmatically-shut-down-spring-boot-application#22944850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a lot of options to shutdown spring-boot application:

Shutdown rest endpoint - add below properites to your application.properties and fire following request `curl -X POST localhost:port/actuator/shutdown`

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*  
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true  
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Also you can call suitable method to shutdown application:

- By calling method `close()` on `ConfigurableApplicationContext` object (it will close application context)
- By passing exit code to method `SpringApplication.exit(ctx, () -> 0);`

Please check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If a bean throws an exception then Spring will not proceed and the process will end.

```
if(ansi.equals("true")) {
     Ansi ansiObj = new Ansi();
     ansiObj.ansi = ansi;
     return ansiObj;
}
else  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("reason");
}
```

I can't say that I've ever had a use-case for it, but I wouldn't say it's necessary bad practice. In this limited example of true and false, it seems a bit unusual. It would make more sense if you needed a constraint on a property e.g. X < 10