# Spring Boot: exit jvm on "Application run failed"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to react on "Application run failed", e.g. in case when database is unavailable?

In my case the desired behavior is to exit the JVM process, so the docker container will be automatically restarted

I tried to listen for "ContextClosedEvent", but it does not work for the startup failure case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944850/175554

Comment: @özkanpakdil do you see there the answer to my question? there is nothing about reacting on "application failed" error

Comment: when database is not available spring boot fails anyway. for other cases I thought you can check how to end running spring boot.

Comment: @özkanpakdil spring boot fails, jvm is still running
the issue is solved using one of spring boot's internal mechanims.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who need to kill application on any failure during startup (example in kotlin):

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val application = SpringApplication()
    application.addListeners(FailedInitializationMonitor())
    application.addPrimarySources(listOf(MyApplication::class.java))
    application.run(*args)
}

class FailedInitializationMonitor : ApplicationListener<ApplicationFailedEvent> {

    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationFailedEvent) {
        exitProcess(1)
    }
    
}
```