# How to close spring boot embedded server

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am developing a cron in that i am using a web client to send a post request to a rest api. I don't want to keep the embedded server on, as cron need to complete its task, in few seconds. But when i don't use the server by:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

it shows the error `Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response`
as it need the server to work, what can i do to stop the server after the response.

I have tried

```
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=20s
```

but its not doing anything (i am using intellij ide)

Update:
I tried

```
SpringApplication.exit(context, (ExitCodeGenerator) () -> 0);
```

But getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@37c7595 has been closed already`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make sure that the SpringBoot application is closed properly and the resources are released back to the operating system,

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

------------------
------------------
int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(context, (ExitCodeGenerator) () -> 0);
System.exit(exitCode);
```

[original question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22944144/6622913)

Comment: Oh its stopping but an error is coming: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@37c7595 has been closed already`